# Probability question on sequences satisfying $a_k \neq k$

Tags: probability, limits

Let $\mathcal{A}_n=\{1,2,\dots,n-1,n\}$
Probability that a injective sequence $a:\mathcal{A}_n\rightarrow \mathcal{A}_n$ satisfies $a_k \neq k$ for all $k \in \mathcal{A}_n$ is equal to $$\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}$$
On the other hand probability that any sequence $b:\mathcal{A}_n\rightarrow \mathcal{A}_n$ satisfies $b_k \neq k$ for all $k \in \mathcal{A}_n$ is equal to
$$\big(1-\frac{1}{n}\big)^n$$
Both expressions tend to $e^{-1}$ as $n \to \infty$ 
I wonder whether there is some reason for this, or is it just a coincidence and if we can replace $\mathcal{A}_n$ by $\mathbb{N_+}$ in a limit.

Comment: The difficulty with replacing $\mathcal A_n$ by $\Bbb N_+$ is that there's no uniform probability distribution over the infinite set of functions $\Bbb N_+\to\Bbb N_+$.

Comment: I hope your main question gets an answer, though. The equality certainly seems like more than just a coincidence, but I've been having trouble coming up with an explanation.

Comment: @Karl thank you for paying attention to this problem. By the way I also came to the conclusion that there isn't uniform convergence on the set of these sequences, but at the same time this seems pretty strange to me, as we can find subsets of this set, for which we can calculate the probability. For example probability of finding a sequence $a_n$ where $a_1$ is divisible by $3$ should be clearly $1/3$. Maybe there is a way of defining this probability function such that its codomain are cardinal numbers, or something like this?